# Makefile: pass SIGTERM signal to subprocess

Tags: makefile, signals, gnu-make

I have the following recipe:

```
sleep:
        trap 'echo "SIGTERM received"; exit' SIGTERM
        echo "falling asleep"
        sleep 30
        echo "waking up"
```

My expectation upon sending SIGTERM to the `make` process is that `SIGTERM received` is printed on the STDOUT and the sleep process is interrupted.

This doesn't happen, instead I get:

```
$ make sleep                                                                                                                                                                
trap 'echo "SIGTERM received"; exit' SIGTERM
echo "falling asleep"
falling asleep
sleep 30
make: *** [Makefile:4: sleep] Terminated
Terminated
```

How to make sure that `make` passes the SIGTERM interrupt to the subprocesses?

Comment: In make, each recipe line runs in its own shell instance, therefore your first recipe line wouldn't effect the recipe line with the sleep.   You could try catenating the lines together using `\\` at the end to make a single shell instance.   That being said, if you did send a sigterm to make, it would not pass that down to the shell instance running your recipe, so that still wouldn't work...

Comment: Concatenating the lines together works, thank you for the suggestion. If you turn your comment into a proper answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: `make` absolutely DOES pass SIGTERM to its children.  Otherwise when you used ^C or whatever make would exit but leave all the child processes running (which could one compile, or be an entire sub-make invocation!)

Comment: Correct, the issue, as @HardcoreHenry explained is that the `trap` and `sleep` are not executed in the same shell, therefore the `trap` is useless and doesn't work as expected.

Comment: My comment was in response to Henry's statement _if you did send a sigterm to make, it would not pass that down to the shell instance running your recipe_; this is not the case.